# split elements from array into array of string of n length

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, reduce

Each element in array have to be less than `n` characters in length, but as long as possible.

Elements from original array have to be joined by `,` (without space).

Let's say `n` is `20`.

I have this array:

```js
[
  "first",
  "second",
  "third",
  "etc"
]
```

I want get this in a end:

```js
[
  "first,second,third",
  "etc"
]
```

I tried using `split` and `join`.

```js
array.split(2).join(',');
```

but splitting it in 2 is not smart, because array length can vary and I can't figure out better way, someone recommended me using `reduce`, but I can't understand `reduce`, still trying to learn it to use in real problems.

Comment: But the length of `first,second,third` is `18` not `20`.

Comment: @Anatolii yeah but if add `,etc` it will be `22` which > `20`, sorry if I wasn't clear in my question, I want it to be as close to `20` but not more than `20`.

Comment: Let's say `n = 3` and `{'1', '2', '34', '56', '7'} - what sequence should we get?

Comment: @Anatolii `1,2`, `34`, `56,7`

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this, using reduce:

```
const originalArray = [
  "first",
  "second",
  "third",
  "etc"
];

const maxSize = 20;

const reducer = (ac, val) => {
  if (ac.length > 0 && ac[ac.length - 1].length + val.length <= maxSize) {
    ac[ac.length - 1] += "," + val;
  } else {
    ac.push(val);
  }
  return ac;
};

const newArray = originalArray.reduce(reducer, []);

console.log(newArray);
```

What reduce does is, basically start with an empty array as a result. Then, process each single item of the original array in this way:

- If the sum of the lengths of the result array last item and the
  processing value is over the maxSize, or if the result array size is
  still empty, add it as a new result array item.
- Otherwise, add it as
  a separated with coma string to the current last item from the result
  array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
const arr = ["first", "second", "third", "etc"];

const result = [];
let i = 0;
arr.forEach(word => {
    if (!result[i]) {
        result[i] = word;
    } else if (result[i].length + word.length + 1 <= 20) {
        result[i] += `,${word}`;
    } else {
        i += 1;
        result[i] = word;
    }
});
console.log(result); // prints ["first,second,third", "etc"]
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or you checking for `word.length` and not for `word.length` + `,`

Comment: @Pleklo, yeah. I missed that, I have edited the answer to account for the "," as well